# Generate a two dimensional array of complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a two dimensional array of a given size containing complex numbers like in this example:

```
>>> generate_array((2, 3))
array([[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 0.+1.j,  1.+1.j,  2.+1.j]])
```

Comment: And? Have you tried it?

Comment: Your question is missing a question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ofcourse I tried it, but I couldn't solve this with standart numpy tutorials, I didn't find the correct function / way to generate this while looking at the docs and couldn't find this question on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this
using `np.indices()` engaged with `np.vectorize()`:

```
def generate_array(dim):
    X, Y = np.indices(dim)
    return np.array(np.vectorize(complex)(X, Y))

ar = generate_array((2, 3))
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.+0.j  0.+1.j  0.+2.j]
 [ 1.+0.j  1.+1.j  1.+2.j]]
```

Comment: Typo: `dim` was not used

Comment: Thanks! Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
def generate_array(m, n):
    return (np.arange(m) * 1j)[:, None] + np.arange(n)


generate_array(2, 3)
Out: 
array([[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 0.+1.j,  1.+1.j,  2.+1.j]])
```